# Why does ES6 Object Destructuring not work with native javascript prototypes?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was messing around with [ES6 Object Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and started to try to define function properties through destructuring. For example:

```js
const obj = {
  test() {
    return console.log('Hello World');
  },
};

const { test } = obj;
test();
```

So then I started wondering if I could define native prototype methods through destructuring. However, this did not work as I expected. Here's an example of me trying to execute the `Array.prototype.forEach()` function through destructuring:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const { forEach } = arr;
forEach((num) => console.log(num))
```

As you can see, I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Array.prototype.forEach called on null or undefined

Does this not work for the same reason as `this` not corresponding to the usual value when inside an arrow function?

```js
Array.prototype.hello = () => console.log(`Hello ${this}`);
[1, 2, 3].hello()

Array.prototype.hello = function() {  return console.log(`Hello ${this}`); };
[1, 2, 3].hello()
```

Comment: You first example does only work because `test` does not require `obj`. If you have `const obj = {
  value: 1,
  test() {
    return console.log('Hello World: '+this.value);
  },
};

const { test } = obj;
test();` it does not work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So then I started wondering if I could define native prototype methods
> through destructuring. However, this did not work as I expected.
> Here's an example of me trying to execute the
> Array.prototype.forEach() function through destructuring

This is not an issue with destructuring, this happens as the context is not set. You have taken the `forEach` reference out of the array and invoked it without any context.

Without destructuring if you do the same, you would get the same error:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const forEach = arr.forEach;
forEach((num) => console.log(num));
```

If you set the context as the array `arr`, explicitly after destructuring it would work:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const { forEach } = arr;
forEach.call(arr, (num) => console.log(num));
```

If you check the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) of `Array#forEach` you would see this line:

```
if (this == null) { throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.forEach called on null or undefined'); }
```

This is in fact the result you get, when you try to invoke the `forEach` without a context. This is required as the `forEach` needs an array context to work. As without the right context, how is the `forEach` going to know which array to iterate or how many elements are present in the array.

Comment: Basically, you are calling a method as if it was a simple lambda function. As you mentioned, you need to declare the scope of the call so that `this` references the array.

Comment: Just for argument's sake, would that mean that `Array.prototype.forEach.call([1, 2, 3], (num) => console.log(num))` would work too?

Comment: @Lioness100 Yes, whatever array you supply as the `this` context through the `call` method would be used by the `forEach` to iterate.